# Difference between method area and stack

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, stack

In this [article](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-jvm-memory-types/) as many others, it says :

> Method area is part of non-heap memory. It stores per-class
>   structures, code for methods and constructors. Per-class structure
>   means runtime constants and static fields.

This is quite confusing for me, because I have just read that stack memory is composed of stack frames where each frame contains method informations such as  local variables and method parameters of a given method.

So what difference there is between the method area memory and the stack memory space (apart from the fact that the first is shared among all threads while the latter is thread-based)?

Comment: The method area contains "runtime constants and static fields". The stack frames "contains method informations such as local variables and method parameters". The former is unchanging (unless your static fields are mutable, shudder); the latter is different per method invocation.

Comment: @AndyTurner where one class method reference is stored then please (talking about java 8+)?

Comment: It’s not clear why you think that “method area” and “stack memory space” had anything in common. There’s no point in asking for the differences between two things which have nothing in common. What are the differences between “air” and “time”?

Comment: I had to make some further readings. I have got a much clearer idea now.